# Signing into my Wordpress blog newsletter from external site - how to?

Tags: codeigniter, wordpress

I want to have a newsletter on my WP blog, and there are plenty of plugins available to do this job. So no problem.

I have external website based on PHP framework, CodeIgniter. And I want to have a form, which allows me to signing into my WP Blog newsletter - is it possible? If yes, how to do it?

These 2 sites are on the same server.

Blog is: 
    www.mysite.com

Webiste is: 
    www.mysite.com/site2/

Comment: Are you talking about integrating your WP site and your CI site and using a single-sign-on method to access both sites? Or are you literally talking about having an external login form that allows you to sign into your WP site?

Comment: I want to integrate only newsletter-signing-in process. It can be both ways, I want only to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WP login form code to submit user id/password from your CI page to wp-login.php. You can set the redirect_to form variable to whatever landing page you want.

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://mysite.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
<p>
    <label>Username<br />
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" /></label>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Password<br />
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" /></label>
</p>
<p class="forgetmenot"><label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90" /> Remember Me</label></p>
<p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="Log In" tabindex="100" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://mysite.com/mysite2/somelandingpage.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
</p>
```